# Breakpoints not getting hit in VSC even with justMyCode = false

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, breakpoints

I am developing in Python using Visual Studio Code. I put breakpoints in the code of an external package in my virtual environment. But the breakpoints are never getting hit. Even by setting the variable justMyCode = false in the VSC settings.

Could there be another reason ?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem.

The reason is that "The venv folder is not used to store external packages. They must be activated to access the modules installed in them, but the code that uses these libraries should remain external."

The solution is to move the external files with breakpoints out of the virtual environment (like "`venv`") folder.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Well, on the project I am working on, such workaround is not really convenient. There is no other way to debug without having to move the files ?

Comment: @bam500 -At present, it is still recommended that you remove the script from the virtual environment folder so that VSCode can better identify the script and breakpoints.