# Can't set breakpoint in library, even with justMyCode cleared

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm running VS Code Version: 1.87.1.

I'm trying to set a breakpoint in a package I've installed into my venv with pip.  When I set the breakpoint, it looks like it's set (red dot on the source line), but when I run my test in debug mode, the breakpoint gets cleared with the message:

```
Breakpoint in file excluded by filters.

Note: may be excluded because of "justMyCode" option (default == true).Try setting "justMyCode": false in the debug configuration (e.g., launch.json).
```

I do indeed have `"debugpy.debugJustMyCode": false,` in my settings.json file.  I've found the four-year old [Breakpoints not getting hit in VSC even with justMyCode = false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64134978/) which sounds like the same problem, but (like the OP in that question), it's not clear how to work around this.

To answer starball's question, I do not have a launch.json file.

Comment: what if you use a launch config and set `justMyCode` in the launch config?